# I want to use anotation @ComponentScan but I get an error "Consider defining a bean of type" SpringBoot 2.1.0.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring-boot

I implemented a simple example for framework, and this a want to do something more complex.

I have a simple `maven` project with `Spring boot 2.1.0.Release`

The structure looks like:

```
package com.springBootLenr.services;

public interface HelloWorldService {
    public String sayHello();
}
```

package Service implement interface service.

```
package com.springBootLenr.services;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Profile("default, english")
public class HelloWorldEnglishImpl implements HelloWorldService{

   @Override
   public String sayHello() {
       return "Hello World in English";
   }
}
```

and all above was called from the controller.

```
package com.springBootLenr.controllers;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import com.springBootLenr.services.HelloWorldService;

@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

    private HelloWorldService helloService;

    @Autowired
    public HelloWorldController(HelloWorldService helloService) {
        super();
        this.helloService = helloService;
    }

    public String greeting() {
        String greeting = helloService.sayHello();
        System.out.println(greeting);
        return greeting;
    }   
}
```

and this is my run application:

```
package com.springBootLenr.springBootLenr;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

import com.springBootLenr.controllers.HelloWorldController;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.springBootLenr")
public class SpringBootLenrApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(SpringBootLenrApplication.class, args);
        HelloWorldController greeting = (HelloWorldController) ctx.getBean("helloWorldController");
        greeting.greeting();
    }
}
```

I was expecting something like `"Hello world in English"` but, I get this error message.

```
/\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.0.RELEASE)

2018-11-08 19:35:35.511  INFO 11072 --- [           main] c.s.s.SpringBootLenrApplication          : Starting SpringBootLenrApplication on xxxxx with PID 11072 (D:\Datos\Proyectos\eclipse-workspace\springBootLenr\target\classes started by Yo_ in D:\Datos\Proyectos\eclipse-workspace\springBootLenr)
2018-11-08 19:35:35.517  INFO 11072 --- [           main] c.s.s.SpringBootLenrApplication          : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-11-08 19:35:36.161  WARN 11072 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'helloWorldController' defined in file [D:\Datos\Proyectos\eclipse-workspace\springBootLenr\target\classes\com\springBootLenr\controllers\HelloWorldController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.springBootLenr.services.HelloWorldService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
2018-11-08 19:35:36.178  INFO 11072 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-11-08 19:35:36.478 ERROR 11072 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.springBootLenr.controllers.HelloWorldController required a bean of type 'com.springBootLenr.services.HelloWorldService' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.springBootLenr.services.HelloWorldService' in your configuration.
```

Comment: whatever you run in your main method is not affected by Spring Context, hence none of your beans registered with annotation are acknowledged when using in the method outside the context.

Comment: You haven't annotated your service with @Service. Hence the error

Comment: You have to annotate your implementation class with @Service annotation instead of Component

Comment: change `@Component` on `HelloWorldEnglishImpl` to `@Component("helloService")` and declare No-arg constructor in `Controller`

Comment: I think @ZhenyangHua overstates the case - but it is convention to just have the call to `SpringApplication.run()` in `main()`, and to have all your code in an instance `run()`  method that Spring will call once the context is set up...

Comment: `@ComponentScan` is redundant in your example. `@SpringBootApplication` enables component scanning for its package.

Comment: @GauravRai1512  `@Service` is a specialisation of `@Component`. Switching to it will have no effect on whether or not the component is found by scanning.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your line:

```
@Profile("default, english")
```

which makes that implementation bean for HelloWorldService only "visible" to Spring when you have activated the "default" or "english" profiles - which you don't do anywhere in your code (unless you have an `application.properties` file you did not mention :-p).

You can search SO for a question on how to enable a profile by default - like "default" in your example -as I don't think it's something that Spring Boot will do for you, unless you make it.

BTW - I think the "proper" syntax is

```
@Profile({"default", "english"})
```

Comment: The `default` profile is automatically active if no other profiles are active. Your point about the syntax still stands though. I suspect that’s what’s causing the problem.